# Popup div on close window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw this post: [pop-up div over parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092782/pop-up-div-over-parent-window) and the message about yensdesign, which is fine, but it still doesn't "quite" cover what i would want, which is:

At this moment I have two popups. One for when the window closes and the other pops up when the visitor has been on the page for x seconds. Downfall of this is:
1. It's [fill in]-ugly
2. One of them looks like a div, the other like a popup (in firefox), while they look like very simple and ugly popups in other browsers.

So I would like to have the same function, but then with divs, so that they will look nicer and behave appropriately amongst all browsers.

The only stuff I can find has code for closing divs... so could someone help me out please?

Edit: See http://www.cornerstws.com/test.html for the simple javascript solution that I had so far.. (popup appears after 3 sec and the other popup appears when you close the window (or refresh.. not nice either)).

Comment: could you please show some code so we can assist you

Comment: @Eric: Sorry.. I just edited my post, so that it has the original javascript popups.

Comment: you cant style a javascript alert box, sorry

Comment: @Eric: Ehm.. yes.. I know! That's why I wrote what I wrote: I would like a div instead of a javascript popup.

Comment: change the alert(); to $('#yourdiv').show(); then style your div with that message and an 'okay' button. I need to see your code, could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Eric: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Q9W/ Sorry, your suggestion isn't in there yet.. haven't had time to look at it yet.

Answer (score 1):

as i understood from ur question that you want a popup that can be triggered through java script function

u can check this blog for a simple popup

http://blog.theonlytutorials.com/a-very-simple-jquery-popup-ready-to-use-code/

and then u can restyle it to meet ur needs and u can use this function

```
$('#pop').click();
```

rather than clicking the link to open the popup.

hope this answer helped you